# How can route in lazy loading children's children Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

## How can restrict route in lazy loading children's children Angular?

> when I >route to `http://localhost:4200/auth/login` login component works and when I route to `http://localhost:4200/login` login component works I want when I route to `http://localhost:4200/login`
> **going to not found page**

`app-routing.module.ts`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
        path: 'auth',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/authentication/authentication.module').then(m => m.AuthenticationModule)
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

`authentication-routing.module.ts`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '', component: AuthenticationComponent, children: [
                {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
                {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
                {path: 'signup', component: SignUpComponent},
            ]
        },

    ]
;

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: You have specifically set the URL of `login` to be `auth/login` when you used `path: 'auth'`, you must declare the route in the root module. The `path` property of nested routes are additive.

Comment: when I add path: 'auth' in auth.module.ts it does the same problem we can reach component
with auth/login and auth/auth/login

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud Adel, in what module is your `authentication-routing.module.ts` imported?

Comment: @Tino in `authentication.module.ts`

Comment: OK. good. And the `authentication.module.ts` is not imported in the the `app.module.ts`, only via lazy loading in the `app-routing.module.ts`. Is that correct?

Comment: yea that correct

Comment: That's odd. As you describe it, it should work exactly as you expect, namely the `LoginComponent` should not appear on http://localhost:4200/login, but on http://localhost:4200/auth/login. Can you share your decisive files on a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) Angular setup with the exact same Angular version as yours.

Comment: @Tino Thank you right I was re-imported it in another shared module by auto imported Webstorm :( now its fixed

Comment:  happy to hear that